# Definition of Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In Rudin chapter 11, there are two places introduce measure.

First, measure is mentioned when he talked about the collection of $\mu$ measurable set $M(\mu)$, and then proof $\mu^*$ is countably additive on $M(\mu)$, and then replace $\mu^*$ by $\mu$, and stated this extended function $\mu$ is a measure.

The second place he mentioned measure is in the section of measure space $(X,M, \mu)$, where $\mu$ is a non-negative countably additive set function defined on $M$, and it is called a measure.

I try to connected these two definitions of measure. May I ask if there is any relationship between $M(\mu)$ (2nd paragraph) and $M$ (3rd paragraph)? So far I think if we have a measure space $(X,M, \mu)$, then $\mu$ must be countably additive on $M$, so $M$ is a subset of $M(\mu)$, where $M(\mu)$ is a collection of all $\mu-$measurable sets.

However, I'm not sure, because the way $M(\mu)$ is constructed at the first place is that we are in $\mathbb{R}^p$, define elementary set $A$ to be a finite union of intervals, and define $\xi$ as the collection of these elementary set. Define $M_F(\mu)$, and for every element $A\in M_F(\mu)$, there exists a sequence $(A_n)\in \xi$ such that $A_n\to A$. And define $M(\mu)$ to be a collection countably union of element in $M_F(\mu)$. It seems like $M(\mu)$ is living in side of the universal set $\mathbb{R}^p$.

On the other hand, in the measure $(X,M,\mu)$, $X$ doesn't have to be $\mathbb{R}^p$ right?

Can I really compare $M(\mu)$ and $M$? Thanks!

Comment: From what you write, the first place seems to be about outer measure ($\mu^*$) and $\mu^*$-measurable sets $M(\mu*),$ with just a mention that $\mu^* | M(\mu^*)$ is a measure (a concept to be defined later).

Comment: $X$ can be any set. I doesn't even have to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n.$